# "Lord, give me strength"

Tags: story-identification

[Over on rec.arts.sf.written](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.arts.sf.written/M-yiPW8AQKc) this question has been asked with no answer forthcoming. Anyone?

> I’m looking for a story ID. I read it many years ago, and it wasn’t new 
>   then. Basic plot: we have a wildly, wildly, WILDLY popular writer of 
>   religious songs who isn’t particularly religious herself but her fans think 
>   she is. Her latest hit has a name something along the lines of “Lord give 
>   me a baby”. It’s a very big hit. And suddenly she has a baby. No 
>   pregnancy. No father. No husband, ‘cause she ain’t married. Big problem 
>   if, when, her fans find out. And then other things start happening. It seems 
>   that she can get anything that she asks for, whether she really wants it or 
>   not, just by praying, which in her case means merely asking God for 
>   something. The story ends with her saying “Lord, give me strength” and 
>   the desk or table or whatever she’s holding starts to break up.
>
> Anyone have any ideas as to what the name might be and who might have 
>   perpetuated it?

Comment: Do we know the original asker is still active? How can we be expected to identify something if you, yourself, can not confirm the identification?

Comment: Gnemlock, if anyone IDs it and its not abundantly clear that the answer is or isn't correct, I'll track down a copy and confirm it for myself. The details given are specific enough that confirming it should be easy.

Comment: And yet here we are, 2 years and 1 month later, no even suggestion of an answer..

Comment: @Gnemlock yep, it must be pretty obscure.